# Fully Configure xampp and PhpMailer to Send Mail

Tags: php, email, configuration, xampp, phpmailer

I've been looking around stack-overflow for help on configuring a website to send mail. So far I've come across specific solutions for specific problems, but not across an answer where there is a tutorial which will help to configure xampp and phpmailer to send mails from scratch.

It would be grateful if someone could provide the answer or a link to a documentations as on how to do it.